# What is "trickling" in terms of bitcoin?

Tags: network, bitcoin-core-development, message

In the Bitcoin (0.10.0) source code I'm coming across the term "trickle".
Could someone please give short but accurate explanations on following instances and tell what they're used for?

1. `bool fSendTrickle`
2. `bool fTrickleWait`
3. `CNode* pnodeTrickle` ?

What is the general idea behind "trickling"?

Answer (score 1):

Trickle is a reference to how the node manages announcing other peers addresses.

Comment: I think a bit more info could be useful here.